# Angular2 + ng2-Uploader UPLOAD_DIRECTIVES is not defined

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

Am trying to use ***ng2-uploader*** in my angular2 app , i'm trying to add a button click upload action in my view , i've tried to do like the documentations explains [`https://github.com/jkuri/ng2-uploader`](https://github.com/jkuri/ng2-uploader)

**component.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {UPLOAD_DIRECTIVES} from 'ng2-uploader/ng2-uploader';

@Component({
  selector: 'demo-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/demo.html',
  directives: [UPLOAD_DIRECTIVES],
})
export class DemoApp {
  uploadFile: any;
  options: Object = {
    url: 'http://localhost:10050/upload'
  };

  handleUpload(data): void {
    if (data && data.response) {
      data = JSON.parse(data.response);
      this.uploadFile = data;
    }
  }
}
```

***component.html***

```
<a href="load" class="clas1" 
       [ng-file-select]="options"
       (onUpload)="handleUpload($event)">

<div>
Response: {{ uploadFile | json }}
</div>
```

but i'm facing this error in my navigator :

> Error: ReferenceError: UPLOAD_DIRECTIVES is not
>   defined(…)ZoneDelegate.invoke @ angular2-polyfills.js:332Zone.run @
>   angular2-polyfills.js:227(anonymous function) @
>   angular2-polyfills.js:576ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @
>   angular2-polyfills.js:365Zone.runTask @
>   angular2-polyfills.js:263drainMicroTaskQueue @
>   angular2-polyfills.js:482ZoneTask.invoke @ angular2-polyfills.js:434

therefore i have taken a look in the ng2-uploader component installed in the node and it looks like this :

```
///<reference path="../../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>
import {Ng2Uploader} from './src/services/ng2-uploader';
import {NgFileSelect} from './src/directives/ng-file-select';
import {NgFileDrop} from './src/directives/ng-file-drop';

export * from './src/services/ng2-uploader';
export * from './src/directives/ng-file-select';
export * from './src/directives/ng-file-drop';

export default {
  directives: [NgFileSelect, NgFileDrop],
  providers: [Ng2Uploader]
}

export const UPLOAD_DIRECTIVES: [any] = [NgFileSelect, NgFileDrop];
```

so it looks like everything is correct , anybody know how to repair this ,  , maybe i should add something to my **boot.ts** or my **index.html** , but what exactly ??

Answer (score 1):

I would try the following SystemJS configuration in your main HTML file:

```
<script>
  System.config({
    map: {
      'ng2-uploader': 'node_modules/ng2-uploader'
    },
    packages: {
      (...)   
      'ng2-uploader': {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
  (...)
</script>
```